# JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor not working correctly with special characters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I am working on a spring-data-jpa project with oracle db. In my project, there is an entity called Booking -

```
@Entity
public class Booking {
  public enum $State { ACCEPTED, REJECTED}
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private $State state;
}
```

I am using hibernate as ORM. To generate metamodel for this entity I am using hibernate-jpamodelgen dependency -

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I run `mvn clean install` on my project, it starts building metamodel files inside target folder. But for this Booking class, it generates -

```
@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(Booking.class)
public abstract class Booking_ {
   public static volatile SingularAttribute<Booking, .State> state;
}
```

During compilation it fails, as `.State` does not exist.
I don't understand why it is converting `$` to `.`.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Any specific reason to use `$` symbol there?

Comment: Sounds like a Hibernate bug to me.

Comment: Legacy system. $ is prefixed for enum. Can't really change the entities so need a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is we cannot use $ in class names.
$ is special character with respect to JAVA class names and internally used by JVM for processing inner classes. For more details check - https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14277